# Segue from and to the same UITableViewController (navigation) - controller reusable?

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am new to iOS development, and I wonder how to do the following task:

I want the user to navigate through a multi-level menu. I have UITableViewController with two different kinds of cells. 
When clicked on cell type number one I want to reload the UITableViewController with different data. (A click on the other cell does something else.)

Do I have to set up a different UITableViewController in the StoryBoard or can I reuse the existing one and segue from and to the same one? I don't know how many levels I will have in the end because the data comes from a remote source. I could have two different UITableViewControllers (because there is one different button), but I'd prefer to do it all in one (and try to hide and show the button when needed).

Anyway, I need to reuse the same class but change the data for each instance. How can I do that? I also need to restore the old state (last used data) of the controller when going back - or does this happen automatically - is it an "unwind" anyway?

Which methods should I override to delegate the new data?

I tried several tutorials but couldn't yet find the information needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What I learned so far is that I can instantiate new view controllers with "let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard-ID‌​")", that I don't need to use segues but I can push and pop new view controllers unto the navigation stack. There is a didSelectRowAtIndexPath method that I can use instead of segues.

Comment: And what is the negative point for? Are beginner's questions not welcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Nav Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html), I'm pretty sure this is what you'll use.

Add UITableViewDelegate to your ViewController press command and click on it for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use a simple variable to keep track.

Declare a variable `var step = 0`

Then in your

```
override func prepareForSegue(){

    step += 1 //and pass that variable to the next view and so one, incrementing by one each time.

}
```

Then in your

```
viewDidLoad(){
   switch step{
   case 0:
       //add this data
   case 1:
       //add this data
   case 2:
       //add this data
   default: break
}
```